# Can someone find out what subdomains I'm hosting?

Tags: linux, subdomain, apache-2.4

I have a vServer with root privileges and **Debian** with **Apache** as web server.

If I create a subdomain using the config files of Apache, `Disallow: /` in the **robots.txt** file as well as telling no-one about the subdomain, **is it possible for anyone to find it out anyway**?

As clarification: I'm **not** trying to reverse engineer. It's about protection of my own server. The subdomain contains "medium classified" information, which shouldn't be available to everyone with the appropriate hacking skills, but is also not worth of strict protection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. There are plenty of services online where you can look up commonly used subdomains for a domain. A lot of that is probably based on search statistics, ad services, and so on, so it may depend on what your vhosts are hosting that determines how available they are. But yes, go and ahead and do a search for `example.com subdomain list` and see what you can find.

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible for anyone to find it out anyway?

Sure. Nothing is preventing people from just brute-forcing the subdomain.

What you are doing is considered [Security through Obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity), and is about as good as no security at all. It's incredibly simple to implement HTTP Basic auth (or digest auth), either of which would increase the amount of protection offered to this subdomain by many orders of magnitude.

Sidenote: adherence to directives in your `robots.txt` is strictly voluntary. Yes, well-behaved search engines will not index your site if you tell them not to, but unfortunately there are plenty of non-well-behaved search engines out there. "Securing" data by a restrictive `robots.txt` is another example of Security through Obscurity.

Comment: I know the term "security through obscurity" and I don't like to do such. But in this case, the data doesn't need to be protected at all. It's just better if you can't reach it so simply. Brute-forcing is not possible with a subdomain name longer than a few characters and basic authentication reduces usability on mobile devices. So basically this isn't really an answer to my question as it only tells me that brute force is possible and I know that. I'm also aware that `robots.txt` is voluntarily. That's just to prevent being displayed on google.

Comment: "Brute-forcing is not possible with a subdomain name longer than a few characters" - I think you underestimate what a script kiddie can accomplish with access to even a very modest bot net. And yes, it does answer your question directly.

Comment: You overlook one fact I stated. The data doesn't *need* to be protected. I heard of ways to figure out / enumerate subdomains, but I don't know if that is true.

Comment: If it doesn't need to be protected then why even ask this question? You directly asked of enumerating subdomains is possible. You have your answer.

Comment: So you are saying that brute force is the only way?